# In webstorm, is there something equivalent to the command pallette found in sublime?

Tags: webstorm

I'm switching from sublime text to [Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) and trying to learn to use it.

What i really miss is the ability to perform the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to open the [command palette](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/command_palette.html). Is there something equivalent to that in Webstorm?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Actually, I found something closer to the command palette:

It's called **Find Action** and can be performed by doing:

Default on PC: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
Default on Mac: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

More on this: [Finding an action](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/navigating-to-action.html)

Comment: Cmd Shit A on OSX.  This is the command palette, whereas double shift is comparable to Sublime's "Go To Anything" Cmd-P (or Ctrl-P).

Comment: @Sk606 lol, you surely meant Cmd+SHIFT+A?

Comment: lol shift you're right :P

Answer (score 8):

#### Sure have.

Just by double <kbd>Shift</kbd> you can search by whole IDE and your current project data using **[Searching Everywhere](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/searching-everywhere.html?search=search)**.

For quickly get more familiar with it I suggest you watch following screencasts:

- [WebStorm Tricks and Tips](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=leKbqNpgoNQ)
- [WebStorm - Things You Probably Didn’t Know](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3yGl4Kfwhs)
- [And many more...](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQ176FUIyIUb0zTe7k4ZKkhMsR-slKu3w)